# Nativescript 7 and Chrome DevTools

Tags: nativescript

I have updated my app to Nativescript 7. One thing I haven't been able to get to work correctly is debugging using Chrome Dev Tools. It does use the Chrome Dev Tools console, but I can't seem to get the Network tab to work or the Elements tab. Has anyone else managed to get it to work?

My app uses Angular 10 and Nativescript 7.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they fixed this in a recent update for NS. Try updating and see if that fixes it.

If not you can update your `package.json` file to use `"@nativescript/ios": "6.5.3",`. That'll use the JSC compiler for iOS instead of the new V8 runtime, then your element and network inspector should work!

Comment: Thanks. I'm using "@nativescript/android": "7.0.1",
    "@nativescript/ios": "7.0.4",